# Postgres add serial column in create table as

Tags: postgresql, select, increment

I need to add a serial field or increasing the id field for each row in a query

The following code is an attempt to do what I want.

```
    create temp table tt_Final as
    SELECT   
        'Transaccion' = Table1.Nombrem,
        Table1.number as "number",
        "Id"= Serial
        from Table1
```

Comment: Are you wanting the new table to share a serial/sequence with Table1. If not, can you not just create a new sequence and use alter table to add it to your new table.

Comment: What is `'Transaccion' = Table1.Nombrem,` supposed to do? You can't assign values like that in a `SELECT` statement